# Autofac, MEF and dotnet core 3.0

Tags: .net-core, autofac, mef

In my application I use Autofac as my DI-Framework and MEF for to dynamically load assemblies into the container. I've done this several times, but with dotnet Framework, not core.

So I have my module:

```
[Export(typeof(IMyModule))]
public class ModueA : IMyModule
{
}
```

The `Export` attribute resides in the namespace `System.Composition`

The `ComposeableCatalog` is registered this way:

```
var catalog = GetComposableCatalog();            
_configuratorContainerBuilder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(catalog);
```

During debugging I can see that the `catalog` holds a property named `LoadedFiles` and this array holds `ModuleA`. But the `Parts` property is empty..

When I build my container and try to resolve all modules that implements `IMyModule`, I get back an empty collection.

```
 using(var container = _configuratorContainerBuilder.Build())
 {
     var modules = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyModule>>();
 }
```

Any ideas where I get this wrong?

Comment: I'm not really a MEF person, but it doesn't seem there's enough to go on here to really help out. We don't know what `GetComposablePartCatalog` does. We can sort of infer what `_configuratorContainerBuilder` is but it'd be nice to see it declared so we're sure. We don't know what versions of things you're working with - which .NET Core SDK, which Autofac, which Autofac.Mef, which System.ComponentModel.Composition. If you could post this as, say, a fully functional unit test so folks could repro it, you might get more help.

Comment: Thanks @TravisIllig I ended up writing my own code to load the assemblies directly and add them to the container

Comment: If the question doesn't matter anymore, consider closing it or deleting it.